# Can you retreive the current logged in user from JWT token?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, jwt

So I am making my first Vue project (with backend REST API) and I just managed to make it possible for a user to log in and get a JWT token. Now I want to make it clear for the user that (s)he is logged in. So in my navigation bar, I want the username to be displayed.

The problem is that I do not know how to do it. Should I store the username in the local storage when logging in?
Should I retrieve the JWT token and try to get the username out of the token?
Or is there another way to do this?

Information to help you answer my question better:

- I am using Vue.js
- I am using a MYSQL database
- I am using a Spring boot REST API

If you need more info I will add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the username in your local store f.e. vuex and then load it in when changing a page / load it in your header